# How to stream adding a logo a scaling

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, cmd.exe, streaming, rtmp

I have this command line,

```
ffmpeg -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect 1 -reconnect_delay_max 4 -i hello.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -vf scale=1024:576 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1300k -acodec aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://test
```

but im getting an error

> Filtergraph 'scale=1024:576' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
> -vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.

What can I do?

Comment: Try replacing `-filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -vf scale=1024:576` with `-filter_complex "overlay=10:10,scale=1024:576"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for u big help !